# PHP Parsing a Date Time String smartly

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a date time string combination to Date and Time and wanted to know if there a smarter way

Sample Data

```
9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM
9/4/2013 1:42:28 PM
9/11/2013 12:01:21 PM
....
```

Here's what I'm doing..Looking thru the list of Date Time string

```
   <?php
   $x = "9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM"
   $ExDt = str_getcsv(trim($x," ");
   $ExDate = $ExDt[0];
   $ExTm = $ExDt[1] . " " . $ExDt[2];
   $ExTime = date("H:i:s", strtotime($ExTm)); // Change to 24 hour format

   echo $ExDate;
   echo $ExTime;

   ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: `strtotime("9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM")` doesnt simply work?

Comment: So the only thing you're changing here is to turn the time into 24-hour?

Comment: What format are your date strings, ie *m/d/Y* or *d/m/Y*?

Comment: Thanks for your response. strtotime("9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM") did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

I feel safer converting with this (timezone not taken into account in the example)

```
$start = '25/12/2013 10:13:46';
$new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $start);
echo $new_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Afaik. the `createFromFormat` converts only `09/04/2013 01:42:28`, but not `9/4/2013 1:42:28`. At least it did not work by me. :S

Answer (score 2):

```
$dt = new DateTime('9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM');
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y');
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: I'd still use `createFromFormat` as that date could be March 9 or September 3.

Comment: @Phil, Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php Those would still be parsed correctly when using `/`

Comment: @Rob I think you misunderstand. In non-US locales (such as Aus), *9/3/2013* is *Sat, 09 Mar 2013*. The `DateTime` constructor however will interpret that date as *Tue, 03 Sep 2013*. Using `DateTime::createFromFormat` allows the developer to remove the ambiguity

Comment: @Rob The point is, we don't know what locale TimB is catering for (all the dates in the question are ambiguous). Using `createFromFormat` instead of the `DateTime` constructor allows a developer flexibility. The alternative is to change the input format to an ISO date (*YYYY-mm-dd*) or use hyphens instead of slashes for non-US date formats (which nobody actually uses). Changing input formats, especially from a CSV file seems much harder to me.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by *"Using m/d/Y in createFromFormat is ambiguous"*. Did you perhaps mean *redundant*? You would tailor `createFromFormat` to match the date format in question. If the dates were *d/m/Y*, you would use `createFromFormat('d/m/Y', ...)`. For US dates, you would use `createFromFormat('m/d/Y', ...)`.

Comment: @Rob I'm sure TimB (the OP) cares what locale it is. If his date strings are not US dates, then your answer will not work correctly

Comment: The dump is from a card reader and comes in only one date time format as shown above. $dt = new DateTime('9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM'); Did Not work.

Comment: PHP makes a few default assumptions about dates based on dashes or slashes, thus: `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy`. If that's not what you want it to assume you have to specify format.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = strtotime('9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM');
echo date('H:i:s',$time); // 08:50:05
echo date('Y-m-d',$time); // 2013-03-09
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = "9/3/2013 8:50:05 AM";
$time = strtotime($x);
echo date('m/d/Y', $time), "\n";
echo date('H:i:s', $time), "\n";
```

## [See the result here](http://codepad.org/l4TnWBvq)

## [read more about date time format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)